# Bootstrap dropdowns require popperJs when using Bootstrap-Select

Tags: c#, bootstrap-4, webforms, bootstrap-select

I'm trying to import bootstrap-select into my Webforms application but when I add the CSS and JS file to the project the dropdown doesn't load properly. How can I add this package to my project without having the error in the title?
It is applying CSS properly fine and without problems. The only thing that doesn't work is the script part.

I'm using a webform application template by Visual Studio 19 in C#.

Bootstrap version: 4.3.1
Jquery version: 3.4.1
PopperJS version: 1.14.0

bootstrap-select version: 1.13.9

I have already tried not to import it using CDN but downloading and adding files locally and that didn't work either.

Head

```
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title><%: Page.Title %> - Mi aplicación ASP.NET</title>

    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
        <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>

    <webopt:BundleReference runat="server" Path="~/Content/css" />
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

    <link href="Content/bubbly_button.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
```

Required scripts are loaded before bootstrap-select in the order they should be imported. :

```
<body id="top">
    <form runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
            <Scripts>
                <%--To learn more about bundling scripts in ScriptManager see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=301884 --%>
                <%--Framework Scripts--%>
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
                <%--Site Scripts--%>
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse bg-dark">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1" runat="server" href="~/">ECEG Migration</a>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="container body-content">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            <hr />
            <div class="top-button bubbly-button custom-fab">
                <i class="fas fa-chevron-up"></i>
            </div>
            <footer>
                <p>&copy; <%: DateTime.Now.Year %> - ECEG_Migration</p>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/1ba00c8269.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

    <script src="Scripts/myScripts.js"></script>
</body>
```

Use of the dropdown inside one placeholder

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="dropdown_year" runat="server" CssClass="form-control m-lateral selectpicker"
                    OnSelectedIndexChanged="dropdown_year_SelectedIndexChanged"
                    AutoPostBack="true" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="All years" Value="All" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
```

I think that I did just the right thing importing that but the dropdown is not working.

Comment: I believe WebForms writes a `<select>` element, while Bootstrap/Popper's "dropdown menu" component uses a `<div>` element. To use Popper, you might have to use a Repeater instead of DropDownList.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import popperjs **before** bootstrap for it to work:

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.15.0/umd/popper.js
```

or following your package imports

```
<asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
<asp:ScriptReference Name="popper.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/Popper/popper.js" />
<asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
```